# How to reduce bitrate with out change video quality in FFMPEG

Tags: c, encoding, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG C library. I'm use modified [muxing.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/muxing_8c-source.html) example to encode video. Video quality is reduce frame by frame when I control bitrate (like 1080 x 720 - bitrate 680k ). But same image I using FFMPEG command line tool to encode same bitrate 680k image quality to not change.

What is the reason for same image and bitrate encoded video quality reduce whan I encode using C API and reason why quality did not change command line tool.

I use :

Command line arg :

- `ffmpeg -framerate 5 image%d.jpg  -c:v libx264 -b:v 64k -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

Muxing.c(modified) Codec setting :

- `fps = 5;`
- `CODEC_ID = H264 (libx264);`
- `Pixel_fmt = yuv420;`
- `Image decoder = MJPEG;`
- `bitrate = 64000;`

The video size are same but quality is reduce frame by frame in muxing.c
but same bitrate video quality is perfect.

please provide how to I reduce bitrate with out change quality using FFMPEG C API.

Comment: can you post your code sample, as I think you should specify an encoding profile

Comment: Alternatively you may trace how ffmpeg command line tool uses libavcodec / libavformat API and compare it with your own approach.

Comment: Check the [H264 guide] (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264). I guess the difference goes to the quantization factor and to the presets of libx264.